# Storing a Json response containing \n and \t in a 2 dimentional array in Java and write to Excel using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I get a JSON response as one single string like below. This string should be extracted into a 2-dimensional array.

1. Wherever the `\t` appears in the `response` it has to be in a new cell in the current row
2. Wherever the `\n` appears it has to increment a row number and write in a new row
3. Write the array list in excel using Apache POI.

**Response:**

```
"type": "TABLE",
"data": "Col_1\tCol_2\tCol_3\nName_1\tPlace_1\tAnimal_1\nName_2\tPlace_2\tAnimal_2\nName_3\tPlace_3\tAnimal_3\n"
```

Comment: Please show your attempted code. We’re not a coding service.

Comment: Have you taken the [tour]? Did you visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I was trying with setWrapText(true) in CellStyle, but then I realized it was just to add an autowrap the String. I am new to post a request. Would add an attempted code next time. Logic from Nagaraju worked for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your response using `\n` which becomes the rows in the excel and then from the row split using `\t` which becomes the column values.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ApachePOIExcelWrite {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");

    String response =
        "Col_1\tCol_2\tCol_3\nName_1\tPlace_1\tAnimal_1\nName_2\tPlace_2\tAnimal_2\nName_3\tPlace_3\tAnimal_3\n";

    int rowCount = 0;

    String rows[] = response.split("\n");
    for (String rowInfo : rows) {
      Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

      int columnCount = 0;
      String[] colInfo = rowInfo.split("\t");
      for (String column : colInfo) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
        cell.setCellValue(column);
      }

    }

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("JavaBooks.xlsx")) {
      workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks a lot Nagaraju! This works perfect. I was trying with CellStyle by setting setWrapText to true. Then realized it was particularly to wrap a String.